# How to kill actually running node application from itself

Tags: node.js

I have a node application that sometimes breaks then restart, but after this restart node process of this application Is still running, it can kill my small VPS server when the app will restart a lot of times and I will not kill these process manually.

How can I kill these processes from the node application?
I have a function that restarts the application, so I want to put some code inside this function that will kill this node process before or after starting a new one.

How the node can kill the process by itself?
I mean about something like `kill PID` or `process.kill(PID)` - but how can I get the PID of the actual running application?

Comment: See https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-exit-from-a-nodejs-program

Comment: How are you managing the process? systemd? This sounds like a system problem rather than something you would solve in nodejs

Comment: Well, apart from fixing the actual issues of whatever it is that causes your node processes to hang around

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to kill the Node instance.

#### process.exit();

In which case, just add `process.exit([code])` to the end of your 'start a new server' function.

In a nutshell, process.exit() kills the node app.

For more information:
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

#### To get the PID

If you still need the PID; you should be able to get the PID with `process.pid`; which returns the PID as a Number.

Comment: Not quite. Sounds like he's trying to kill a previous process of the same script

Comment: Yea, the post is a little confusing, but the title specifies "from itself", so I'm betting on process.exit();